# Using a variable taken from a method in an another method

Tags: java, variables, methods

I want to use the variable that is taken from the inputString() method into the countWords() method below, but I unfortunately run into errors when I try using the latter in the main() method. How do I work around this?

```
import java.util.*;

public class WordCounter {
    public static String inputString(){
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("\nInput your desired sentence/string: ");
        String userInput = s.nextLine();
        return userInput;
    }

    public static void countWords(int count, String userInput){

        count = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < userInput.length() - 1; i++)
        {
            if ((userInput.charAt(i) == ' ') && (userInput.charAt(i + 1) != ' '))
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.print("Number of words in the sentence/string: " + count);    
    }

    public static void main (String [] args){
        System.out.println("Word Counter.");
        inputString();
        countWords();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Learn to return values, and pass values

1. Capture the return value coming from your `inputString` method.
2. Pass that returned value to your `countWords` method.

Change this:

```
inputString();
countWords();
```

… to this:

```
String input = inputString();  // Capture the return value.
countWords( input );           // Pass the captured value.
```

And it looks like `count` in `countWords` is supposed to be the result. So that should be returned to the calling method.

```
String input = WordCounter.inputString();
int count = WordCounter.countWords( input );
```

And alter your `countWords` to return that value. Change the declared return type from `void` to `int`. Add a `return` line at the end.

```
public static int countWords( String userInput ){
    … 
    return count ;  
}
```

---

## OOP

Looking at the bigger picture, try to avoid `static` as a student learning [object-oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming).

Create multiple classes, where each class has one main responsibility. If we look at your business problem, we have three responsibilities:

- Business logic: Analyzing text to count words.
- User interface: Interacting with user on the console.
- An app to run the show, with its `main` method.

You might start with three classes.

First, the business logic.

```java
package work.basil.example.wordcounter;

import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

// Takes a string, analyzes to determine a count of words, and returns that count.
public class WordCounter
{
    private CharSequence text;

    public WordCounter ( final CharSequence input )
    {
        this.text = input;
    }

    public int wordCount ( )
    {
        return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt( 0 , 10 ); // Fake method. Put your code here.
    }

    public CharSequence text ( )
    {
        return this.text;
    }
}
```

The console input manager.

```java
package work.basil.example.wordcounter;

public class ConsoleInputGatherer
{
    public String gatherInput ( )
    {
        // Fake method. Write your code here.
        return "your text goes here.";
    }
}
```

And the main app.

```java
package work.basil.example.wordcounter;

public class App
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        App app = new App();
        app.demo();
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        String input = new ConsoleInputGatherer().gatherInput();
        int count = new WordCounter( input ).wordCount();

        // Report results.
        System.out.println( "Input: " );
        System.out.println( input );
        System.out.println( "… has a word count of: " + count );
    }
}
```

When run:

```
Input: 
your text goes here.
… has a word count of: 3
```

---

## Avoid `char`

And, by the way, the `char` type has been essentially broken since Java 2, and legacy since Java 5. As a 16-bit value, it is physically incapable of representing most characters. Instead, to work with individual characters, use [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integer numbers.

Comment: I never thought about declaring a new string to make the countWords() method work, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This way your code should work

import java.util.Scanner;

public class WordCounter {

```
public static String inputString(){
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("\nInput your desired sentence/string: ");
    String userInput = s.nextLine();
    return userInput;
}

public static void countWords(int count, String userInput){

    count = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < userInput.length() - 1; i++)
    {
        if ((userInput.charAt(i) == ' ') && (userInput.charAt(i + 1) != ' '))
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    System.out.print("Number of words in the sentence/string: " + count);
}

public static void main (String [] args){
    System.out.println("Word Counter.");
    String input = inputString();
    countWords(0, input);
}
```

}